# Catia Visual Basic Macro - change external reference link

Tags: vba, catia

I'm wondering if there is any solution for my problem:

In CatiaV5, is it possible to change the external reference link using an Visual Basic (catvba or catscript) macro?
For every CatPart or CatProduct we have an external link to reference like in the picture below:

[image: image here]

***Thank you very much!***

Comment: That is not an external reference. Normally that field references the document (CATPart or CATProduct) itself.

To see referenced documents, select the document in the tree and choose Edit->Links.

Yes you can replace a part in an assembly if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but i'm wondering if there is a way that i can do that using an VBA macro.

Comment: ReplacingParts/Products is possible via the _ReplaceComponent_ method. Or you can try to change the order in linked document localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The *Link to Reference* cannot be altered by API** (VBA/CATscript). It is a read-only attribute which shows:

- the full path of the save location if data is stored filebased:

> "C:\TEMP\part1.CATPart"
> [example with filebased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnYC3.png)

- some ID or name attribute if data is stored on a database system (like enovia VPM)

> 17_83032|00_A02_-___BROKEN_DRW_LINKS [example with database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP6JK.png)

However, the *Link to Reference* will change if you save the part/product to a new location with *save as* - as also stated [here](https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=440399).